# Making a blog; can't decide between MongoDB and MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb, blogs

Right, so I'm about to start writing a blog for my website using Node.js (as much as a learning process as anything), and I've been fiercely debating with myself which of either MySQL or MongoDB to use.

Searching around has produced a few "how to write a blog in Mongo" guides, but they don't seem to cover the sort of things I'm running into issues with. Here's my dilemma:

If I was to use *MySQL*, I would imagine my schema being something along these lines:

#### Posts:

```
ID, USER, DATE, TITLE, TAGS
```

#### Comments:

```
POST_ID, USER, DATE, MESSAGE
```

#### Users:

```
ID, SCREEN_NAME, IMAGE_URL
```

So, each post has associated comments, and posts and comments have associated users. The advantage is that if a user wishes to change their screen name, or image, only one row in the users table needs to be updated. However, offhand I'm not sure however how I would, say, get all of the posts containing X tags, unless perhaps I have multiple fields for multiple potential tags?

Alternately, using something like *MongoDB*, I was looking at formatting it like this:

#### Posts collection:

```
{ 
    {
    _ID: something
    USER: {id: id, name: "screen name", image: "image_url"}
    DATE: ...
    TITLE: ...
    TAGS: [tag1, tag2...]
    COMMENTS: 
         [
         {USER:someone, DATE:something, MESSAGE:"hi"},
         {USER:someone, DATE:something, MESSAGE:"another message"}
         ]
    },
    {
    _ID: something,
    USER: {id: id, name: "screen name", image: "image_url"},
    DATE: ...
    TITLE: ...
    TAGS: [tag1, tag2...]
    COMMENTS: 
         [
         ...
         ]
    },
}
```

So, comments are embedded within each post, which seems natural.

Here, one query can retrieve me all of the posts which match which is great. On the other hand, what if I need to update the screen name or image that a user uses? It seems hard to dig into embedded objects within a given document, let alone update all of the relevant records across every post.

I could move the comments into a separate collection to make them more accessible, but I'd still be faced with doing lots of updates on things like screen names.

#### So...

Essentially, I would prefer to use MongoDB, as what it can do, it can do very easily, and getting to work with one language across the board is nice. However, I cant help but feel that I need to adopt a relational approach in order to get things done "properly".

Has anyone had any experience doing something similar in either, or both languages?

What is your take on this, and specifically how do you handle the relationship between users and comments/posts?

Thanks in advance for any help :)
James

Comment: Use Disqus for comments, use Jekyll for deploying - 10 mins and you're up with a totally maintainable setup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question most definitely does not come down to performance since both MongoDB and SQL would pick a small dataset such as this the exact same way and so there would be no real measurable performance gain.

The main idea of MongoDB in this situation is the ability to nest many tables within one and so making less queries to update your information, for example, instead of querying 12 tables you just query one. Not only that but sometimes the schema can be more natural to how you actually use the data.

I would change a few things in your schema:

```
USER: {id: id, name: "screen name", image: "image_url"}
```

This should just be an `ObjectId` that relates to a user row and again in the comments:

```
{USER:someone, DATE:something, MESSAGE:"hi"}
```

use an `ObjectId` for the `USER` field. These `ObjectId`s would relate to a user collection. Also take out those capital letters, I sense that will be a pain to code around.

As for dealing with relations:- you nest repeatable information to an entity as subdocuments (which would normally be normalised out in 1st NF), however that doesn't mean you should nest to infinity, 3 levels maximum is normally advisable for querying compatibility also bare in mind the boundaries of app entities such as `blog`, `post` and `user`.

Now you have to manage none nested relations such as the `blog` and `user` row (since posts will have comments etc nested). The way to solve these relations is client side, since MongoDB has no relational ideals (it's a RDB heretic).

You would simply do what MySQL would normally do server-side client side, of picking out the user individually and then picking out the posts based on that user id instead of picking out a huge result set of each row being a join between user and post tables.

Comment: Hiya, the capital letters were only for demo purposes, to keep it consistent with how I wrote the mySQL bits :)


As for the user row; that's interesting. I deliberately embedded user data so that the queries would be reduced; having user data somewhere else means quering to retrieve the image/name for the user of each comment, which did not strike me as correct

Comment: @lytnus The problem with embbedding this information is the manner in which it has to be updated. Imagine a user wishes to change their username, this would mean you would have to go through all posts and/or comments and update that users username, it very unscalable. In this instance the user row should be separate. So this is another way of considering whether something should be embbedded or not, as to whether it only is concerned with that item, like comments are only concerned with posts.

Comment: Thanks; I think my main concern was the amount of queries I'd have to make. I guess it's a trafeoff; you eiher make lots of queries each time you want to view the comments, but only a single query to update user info, or lots of queries to update user info but only a single query to read comments. If reading comments happens a lot more, I could see it being worthwhile leaning towards the embedded approach. Either way, my mind is at rest now, and I'm going to go with MongoDB :)

Comment: @lytnus Yes also MongoDB is designed for a read heavy scenario so the number of queries doesn't really matter, it is a case of throwing out that SQL rule book when doing NoSQL. Infact the cursor itself streams straight from the DB unlike SQL which reads from a specific result set written to either memory or disk. So everytime you get a new row from the database through a cursor you are actually runnning that query all over again on the database.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the useful information! It's also easier to get started with and use, so I'm won over!

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that a relational approach is required to get things done properly.

The decision hinges on whether or not you can dispense with ACID and relational niceties.

If your blog is document based, perhaps a NoSQL approach will work fine.

Better yet, you can abstract the details of how you persist things behind an interface and swap one implementation out for another if you're using an object-oriented language like Java or C#.  You need not be locked in that way.

Comment: I guess my question is really, if you dispense with the relational niceties, how do you handle the aforementioned relationships between users and posts, such that doing things like updating user screen name etc can be done in an efficient way?

Comment: NoSQL tends to be more document-based.  If your use cases don't lend themselves to that approach, then your decision is made for you.

Comment: If you had to create a blog then, with similar requirements to mine (pretty basic blog stuff, really), would you take the relational or NoSQL approach? For you, would the downsides of having to update lots of things when a user changed their screen name, for instance, outweigh the benefits of the faster document based access that the NoSQL approach brings? Would your schema differ from mine, above?

Comment: I don't know that document access with NoSQL would be faster; neither do you.  If you store each blog entry as a CLOB in the relational database it's not much different than NoSQL.

Comment: @lytnus You won't really know the difference in performance until you get to super large datasets. When pulling a small blog MySQL and NoSQL would be the same speed since they both pull the same way. That's why this question doesn't really have an answer since it comes down to your preference, it's too subjective.

Comment: Yeah; you're right I'm sure. I just like taking scalability into account from the word go, even though I realise for my own purposes its highly unlikely I'll ever need to worry about it :) Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score -7):

I'd just use wordpress, it's incredibly popular, and I've never had any performance problems with it!  25% of the websites throughout the world today use wordpress!

Comment: I agree that wordpress is a good choice, I'm doing this as a learning exercise using node.js (not PHP), and so that is not really applicable to me.

Comment: What a nice solution? Do you even bothered reading the issues he posted before commenting. Out of topic reply.